# JSON services in Window Phone

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, json.net

I created a apps in Android which is using JSON services. Now i am working in Window phone. I am New here and do not know anything except .net programming. I also want to use JSON service for retrieve data from php file. So please any one tell me . From where i should be start ? may you provide me any sample or source code? or any basic idea . so i will learn it quickly and will able to create JSON service in WINDOW PHONE.

one other :- i've installed visual stdio 2010 . should i need to install other software , sdk etc ?

please window expert guide me.

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my blog post [Parsing JSON in a Windows Phone Application](http://nkishorchandra.blogspot.in/2012/10/parsing-json-in-windows-phone.html).You can find all the details there.

I have used [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for parsing the json data. You can get it from this [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json). And if you dont know how to install and use a Nuget package, [Check Here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)

Comment: thank u for your reply. first i need to install window phone sdk . i got error during run sdk. i just installed visual stdio 2010. plz guide me . what is next product i need to install . what is complete installation of window phone. thank you . i am feeling very helpful of your answer.

Comment: if you have problems with WP sdk installation, you have to ask a separate question for that. For any other doubts, [ask here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17226/windows-phone-7-8)

Comment: JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);  JObject could not found error. please tell me how can i add json.net package . thank