# Window phone sdk is not installing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am a android developer . and now interested in window phone also . i just kept my question visit [JSON services in Window Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750484/json-services-in-window-phone/14750802#comment20643790_14750802) about JSON service and got good answer. but before starting it . i need to install window sdk.  i have installed to visual stdio 2010 . but when i am trying to install window phone sdk . i got error. i have tried to all sdk version .but not installed . do i need to use other software ? or do i am doing mistake.?
please take your time

thank

Comment: What SDK version are you using?
What's the error message?
Note that WinPhone8 SDK requires Windows8 64bit to run (and Windows8 Pro if you wan't to use the emulator). 
A VisualStudio installation is not required as the SDK will install the correct express version if no other valid VS version is found on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install WP 7.1 SDK first, and then 7.1.1 Update and finally 7.8 Update

Find the following links

[WP 7.1 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27570)

[WP 7.1.1 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29233)

[WP 7.8 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36474)

Comment: got error during install to wp 7.1 sdk. server pack 1 must be install message . can not run in compatibility mode message

Comment: Go to [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) and download SP1

Comment: thank taking download time and install . will come back .